# UItableView - UITableViewCell change editingStyle dynamically

Tags: iphone, uitableview, edit

i have a table which has an edit mode. When in edit mode the rows have an uitextfield. If something is entered in the textfield i add a row below the row with the textfield. Everything is fine. Now i want to change the editStyle of the cell with the textfield from `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` to `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`. I tried it with reloading the cell but then the table has some strange scroll behavior then.

Is there any other way to change the EditingStyle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't delete row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577219/uitableview-deleterowsatindexpaths-dont-deletes-row)

Comment: thx for reply but i dont know how this should help me. i dont know if u get my question right. Everthing is fine with my table. I just want to change the editstyle indicator left of the cell at position n-1 without using any reloadmethod because this scrolls the table.